# buttons are all highlighted

Tags: c++, winapi

I have two buttons. Each button is highlighted instead of just the first one. How do I make the first button to be only the one highlighted?

[image]

BTW This is the code for the two buttons:

```
openFileButton = CreateWindowA("button", "Open File and start hashing", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_CENTER, 220, 210, 200, 50, hWnd,
                (HMENU)BUTTON_OPEN_FILE, NULL, NULL);
  SendMessage(openFileButton, WM_SETFONT, my_font, true);
  hashFileButton = CreateWindowA("button", "Get the File hash", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_CENTER, 220, 270, 200, 50, hWnd,
                (HMENU)BUTTON_HASH_FILE, NULL, NULL);
  SendMessage(hashFileButton, WM_SETFONT, my_font, true);
```

Tried using `SetFocus` but got no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, stop calling the `A` versions of WinAPI functions. Those went obsolete back in the '90s. Use the `W` versions instead, with `L` prefixes on your string literals and `wchar_t` as your character type.

Second, you are passing the wrong style flags for buttons. Specifically, you are passing `SS_CENTER`. This is a [style for *static* controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/static-control-styles) (hence the `SS_` prefix), not [for buttons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/button-styles). `SS_CENTER` is #defined in the Windows header files as the value 0x1, which is equivalent to the button style, `BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON`. (Note that #define macros are not type-safe, so the compiler doesn't know and can't warn you that you're specifying a static-control style when creating a button control.)

The presence of this erroneous `BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON` style is why your buttons are both appearing highlighted, as if they are the default button in a dialog box. For standard buttons, you want `BS_PUSHBUTTON`, which is #defined as the value 0x0, and thus equivalent to not passing any style flags to your `CreateWindow` function. But for readability and self-documenting code, I would strongly recommend explicitly passing `BS_PUSHBUTTON`.

So, your corrected code becomes:

```cpp
openFileButton = CreateWindowW(L"button",
                               L"Open File and Start Hashing",
                               WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
                               220, 210, 200, 50,
                               hWnd,
                               (HMENU)BUTTON_OPEN_FILE,
                               NULL,
                               NULL);
SendMessage(openFileButton, WM_SETFONT, my_font, true);

hashFileButton = CreateWindowW(L"button",
                               L"Get the File Hash",
                               WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
                               220, 270, 200, 50,
                               hWnd,
                               (HMENU)BUTTON_HASH_FILE,
                               NULL,
                               NULL);
SendMessage(hashFileButton, WM_SETFONT, my_font, true);
```

You might actually want to make *one* (and only one) of your buttons into the "default" button using the `BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON` style. The behavior is easily implemented by calling the [`IsDialogMessage` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isdialogmessagew) within your main message loop (behavior which you would get for "free" by creating a dialog box, with the added boon of the Resource Editor to lay out the controls and set styles).

Comment: It worked properly after changing to ``BS_PUSHBUTTON``. Didn't notice that ``SS_CENTER`` was the culprit.